# Unable to Import org.apache.log4j.Logger

Tags: java, jdeveloper

I am unable to import the library `org.apache.log4j.Logger` using JDeveloper 10.1. What is the procedure to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean? what's the error you're getting? what build system are you using? I don't think anybody can help you with your request as it is now...

Comment: Is it part of your build path?

Answer (score 5):

Right button on the project name (in navigator panel)/ properties/Libraries and classpath/add jar-directory and select the log4j.jar or download it from the internet
press ok and add the correct import when requested on your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have the jar file in the project directory, it can be downloaded from here.
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/l/Downloadlog4j1215jar.htm

The next step is to add the import in your java class file as:

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;